# How to add int to array of ints?

Tags: arrays, int, append, d

I need to add single `int` to array of `int`s. How can I do it with D?

```d
void main()
{
    int v = 2;
    int [] x ~= v; // do not work
}
```

Working code:

```
int v = 2;
int [] x; 
x ~= v;
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Appender`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.Appender).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a single int to an existing array, you must declare the array first:

```d
int[] x;
x ~= 2;
```

You can also initialize the array with a single int:

```d
int[] x = [2];
```

Comment: So it's impossible to fill array at moment if it's creation?

Comment: The second sample there: `int[] x = [2];` will fill it when it is created.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe yes, I understand. I just trying to understand why `int [] x ~= v;` do not working.

Comment: At construction time, nothing exists to append to yet.

Comment: Can't he technically do [v] which will do what he wants to achieve. Unless he wants to append multiple dynamically then there's not much. It can be hacked through ctfe though